# Find missing route in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am working on a transportation data.

```
Origin Destination (... other columns)
CityA  CityB
CityA  CityC
```

I want to find out missing origin-destination pairs meeting the following recruitment:

1. If we have CityA(origin) -> CityB(destination), but we don't have CityB(origin)-> CityA(destination), then out put CityB(origin)-> CityA(destination).
2. If we have CityA(origin) -> CityB(destination), and we have CityB(origin)-> CityA(destination), then output nothing.

Sample intput:

```
Origin Destination (... other columns)
CityA  CityB
CityA  CityC
```

Sample output:

```
 Origin Destination (... other columns)
    CityB  CityA
    CityC  CityA
```

What I tried:

```
with t1 as (
select distinct t.ofips, t.dfips 
from table t
),

t2 as (
select distinct t.ofips, t.dfips 
from table t
),

t3 as (
select distinct t1.ofips, t1.dfips
from t1
inner join t2
on t1.ofips = t2.dfips
and t1.dfips = t2.ofips 
),

t4 as (
select distinct t1.ofips, t1.dfips
from t1
left join t3
on t1.ofips = t3.ofips
and t1.dfips = t3.dfips
where t3.ofips is null or t3.dfips is null
)--,
select * from t4
```

However, the results seem incorrect. What's wrong with the code? Am I missing something?

Note: Performance is a issue because the table is fairly big.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT
    t1.dfips AS Origin,
    t1.ofips AS Destination
FROM t t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1
    FROM t t2
    WHERE
        t2.ofips = t1.dfips
        AND t2.dfips = t1.ofips
);
```

<kbd>[**ONLINE DEMO**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/631694)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
select t.destination as origin, t.origin as destination
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.origin = t.destination and t2.destination = t.origin
                 );
```

I'm not sure what your query does, but it seems much too complicated.